# Opposite of Cover Vertical transition in Storyboards

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I was wondering how i could create a segue with the exact opposite transition of cover vertical! Cover Vertical comes from bottom to top, i want a top to bottom transition. How could i achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question can be answered by another [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779563/custom-segue-animation)

And from [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html)

The key is to implement your own `- (void)perform` method. Before the `+ animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` method, set the viewController.view.origin to be below the screen and in the animations block adjust it's height.