# iOS push BottomBar and ToolBar simultaneously

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uitoolbar, pushviewcontroller

I have an `UITableView` with TabBar (BottomBar) and ToolBar. When selecting a cell the detailsView is push to the stack. The detailsView does not have a TabBar nor a ToolBar. This is done within the `prepareForSegue` method:

```
...
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"])
{
    ...
    editDetailsViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;    // for hiding the TabBar
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES];   // for hiding the toolbar
}
```

Now everything work fine but when the cell is selected the ToolBar is switched off immediately in the table view immediately before the detailsView is shown.
How do I prevent that behavior? The ToolBar and TabBar should move together without switching off either of them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is fine:

```
...
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"])
{
    ...
    editDetailsViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;    // for hiding the TabBar
}
```

However, `prepareForSegue` is called before the push.

If you want the toolbar to hide with an animation you should [implement a Custom UISegue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779563/custom-segue-animation) and animate the `UIToolbar` in the transition.

Comment: Thanks Nikola, I assumed that the content of the `prepareForSegue` is called after the push. I'll try to follow the proposal of the added link.

Comment: Good luck! Keep in mind that the example in the link is about a completely different animation and in your case, you should figure out how to animate your toolbar.

Comment: Yes I know. I'm still surprised that I need to implement a custom animation for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should comment this line.

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES];
```

and try again.

Comment: Thanks looyao, I tried this before but this leads to an even worse looking behavior: the ToolBar is switched off and will leave its occupied space black in the tableView. in the detailsView the ToolBar appears very short and will disappear again.